# Django Allauth - int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the user from a model into a view, however I keep getting a type error:

**Type error - int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor'**

When I get to the user I have the following:
 django.db.models.fields.related.ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor object at 0x7f4a15299590

Models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class SocialAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(allauth.app_settings.USER_MODEL)
    provider = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('provider'),
                                max_length=30,
                                choices=providers.registry.as_choices())

    uid = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('uid'),
                          max_length=app_settings.UID_MAX_LENGTH)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('last login'),
                                      auto_now=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('date joined'),
                                   auto_now_add=True)
    extra_data = JSONField(verbose_name=_('extra data'), default='{}')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('provider', 'uid')
        verbose_name = _('social account')
        verbose_name_plural = _('social accounts')

    def authenticate(self):
        return authenticate(account=self)

    def __str__(self):
        return force_text(self.user)
```

Views.py

```
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialToken, SocialAccount
def sc(request):
   user = SocialAccount.user
   token = SocialToken.objects.filter(account__user=user, account__provider='soundcloud')
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to post your full stacktrace please?

Comment: @ShangWang What else should I update in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, SocialAccount is the model itself, not a particular instance of it. You would need to actually query for the account you want, like you do with the token.

But I'm not sure why you are doing anything with SocialAccount in the first place. You actually want the user, which is presumably just `request.user`; use that instead.

Comment: You made my day :) Thanks